# Abstracting a js validation method

Tags: javascript, validation

I on my website I currently have several forms on different pages. Each of which calls a js validation method when they are submitted. (They are also validated server side, I just do it in js as well to prevent unnecessary page refreshes). This validation method varies from page to page. For example for the register page it checks if the user already exists, if all fields are filled in and if the passwords match. On the contact page it only checks if the 2 emails match. Now to me it seems stupid to have each of these validation methods separate, as several of the checks they do are done elsewhere. Is there some kind of way in which I could abstract this?

Comment: Could you include a common js file?

Comment: Look at this link: http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/